# Casperjs click button doesn't do anything

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

So I have a html page which has a paragraph and button. When the button is clicked, the paragraph hides. I'm trying to automate this in Casperjs. So far, I load the page, take a screenshot, then click the button and take another screenshot. However, the screenshots are the same

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://localhost:3000/example.html', function() {
    this.echo("Loaded successfully.");
    casper.capture("screenshot1.png");
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.evaluate(function() {
        this.click('//*[@id="hide"]')
    });
});

casper.then(function(){
    casper.capture("screenshot2.png");
});

casper.run();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use this.click() in evaluate() because the code in evaluate() will execute the code as if you were using the browser console.You can use javascript to get the element and use its click() event or you can just use this.click() directly.Anyway,don't use this.click() in evaluate().

Answer (score 0):

This Could be the code if your button id='hide' as you describe your question:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://localhost:3000/example.html', function() {
    this.echo("Loaded successfully.");
    casper.capture("screenshot1.png");

    casper.click('#hide'); // Clicking button with Id='hide'

    casper.capture("screenshot2.png"); // capture after clicking button
});

// Execute the whole process
casper.run();
```

May this will helpful to you! Tx